# opening multiple files using freopen in c++

Tags: c++, stdin, freopen

I'm trying to use freopen() multiple times to read and close different files.
So here's what I did inside my main function:

```
if (argc != 5) {
    std::cerr << "Wrong format of arguments given." << endl;
    return -1;
}
std::string command, command2;
freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
// do something...
fclose(stdin);
freopen(argv[2], "r", stdin);
freopen(argv[3], "w", stdout);
while (std::cin >> command) {
    std::cin >> command2;
    // run some function...
}
fclose(stdin);
fclose(stdout);
```

But it turns out that the first part, `// do something...`, works fine (reads from `std::cin` without a problem) but the while loop in the second doesn't seem to run.
The input files are of correct formats, so I don't know why `std::cin >> command` returns false.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What is the use-case? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve this way? Would it not be better to use proper `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line `freopen(argv[2], "r", stdin);` you are trying to reopen `stdin`. But you have already closed `stdin` in line `fclose(stdin);` just before that. *Also*, `stdin` is now dangling pointer after closing the *file*.

Following is an extract from [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/):

> If a new filename is specified, the function first attempts to close any file already associated with stream (third parameter) and disassociates it. Then, independently of whether that stream was successfuly closed or not, freopen opens the file specified by filename and associates it with the stream just as fopen would do using the specified mode.

You should use `fopen()` function after closing `stdin`.